# How to use fwrite() to insert html from curl into a newly created page

Tags: php, html, curl, fwrite

I am using what appears to be standard fwrite code to insert html into a new page. The code takes input from a html form (url) grabs the source code using a proxy and creates a new page titled with a timestamp. All that works, what is not working is writing the html source code into the new page.

The bellow outputs a timestamp and creates a new page, however the page is empty whereas it should have code in it. Any pointers or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
    <? $url = $_POST['url'];
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '123.30.185.86:3128');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_exec ($ch); $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch); 

$FileName = time();
$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'w') or die("can't open 

file");
fwrite($FileHandle, $curl_scraped_page);

curl_close($ch);

echo $FileName; ?>
```

Comment: and why are you proxying through Vietnam? http://api.fatherstorm.com/?rdns=123.30.185.86

Comment: this is to scrape bits of content, but do not want to store it in a database out of storage constraints. What better place to proxy then Vietnam?

Comment: set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to TRUE if you want to get the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl_exec ($ch); $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
```

should be just

```
 $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
```

and to output what you fetched...

```
echo  $curl_scraped_page;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead.

This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.